# cant unlock my secondary HDD

Tags: hard-drive, encryption, luks, 17.10

I just made the upgrade to Ubuntu 17.10 and I am trying to unlock my secondary HDD. I am sure it is just because I am missing something PLEASE HELP. I encrypted it using LUKS. This disk drive has all my homework and personal files. Here is the error message I keep getting.

[image: enter image Error Unlocking Secondary]

Comment: It's complaining that you're not using the correct password. If you're sure you using the correct password (or keyfile), did you by chance backup the encryption headers?

Comment: No I did not back up anything I did a fresh install of 17.10 I did  other realize there were key files.... so is this hdd  and everything on it gone?

Comment: There would only be a keyfile if you opted to create the LUKS partition with a keyfile rather than a password. Your stuff is likely still there, you just need to use the correct password. If your encryption headers have somehow become corrupted, then yeah, you'd be up the creek without a backup of those headers. Make sure you have `cryptsetup` installed, and try decrypting from a terminal: `sudo cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/sdb1 myLUKS`. If that works, you should be able to mount the decrypted partition from a file manager or the terminal.